# Building multilib GCC cross-compiler targetting FreeBSD?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, cross-compiling, freebsd

**NB:** <s>Now, I hope I got the terminology right here. If not, feel free to point out the right term instead of "multiarch".</s> A commenter pointed out that the correct term would be **multilib**, so I adjusted that in the title (but not in the body) of the question.

What I want to achieve is to build a cross-compiler that is hosted and built on a x86_64 Linux and targets FreeBSD 7.x for both x86_64 **and** x86_32. That is, I'd like the `-m32` and `-m64` switches of `gcc` to work properly.

What I managed to do so far was to build a GCC 5.1 on x86_64 Linux to target the x86_64 on FreeBSD.

Using `-dumpspecs` tells me that the compiler (driver) should be prepared to also build `-m32`:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$MYPREFIX/lib $MYPREFIX/bin/x86_64-pc-freebsd6-gcc -dumpspecs|grep m32
%{m32:--32} %{m64:--64} %{mx32:--x32}
%{!static:--eh-frame-hdr}   %{m32:-m elf_i386_fbsd}   %{p:%nconsider using '-pg' instead of '-p' with gprof(1)}   %{v:-V}   %{assert*} %{R*} %{rpath*} %{defsym*}   %{shared:-Bshareable %{h*} %{soname*}}     %{!shared:       %{!static:         %{rdynamic:-export-dynamic}       -dynamic-linker %(fbsd_dynamic_linker) }     %{static:-Bstatic}}   %{symbolic:-Bsymbolic}
```

But evidently the linker is not prepared. Looking for libraries `gcc`, `gcc_s` and `c`, it fails during the linking stage. Now I know where to get the `libc` from - the FreeBSD distro which I target (in this case x86_32, or in FreeBSD jargon: i386). But the GCC runtime would still have to be built by me, I reckon.

When looking at the documentation:

> `--enable-multiarch` Specify whether to enable or disable multiarch
>   support. The default is to check for glibc start files in a multiarch
>   location, and enable it if the files are found. The auto detection is
>   enabled for native builds, and for cross builds configured with
>   --with-sysroot, and without --with-native-system-header-dir. More documentation about multiarch can be found at
>   http://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch.

it sounds as if multiarch is a glibc-only feature. So is multiarch not what I'm looking for? What term would I be looking for instead?

I'm also wondering whether it is at all possible to build a recent GCC (I was using 5.1) to target both 32-bit and 64-bit x86 FreeBSD 7.x?

If it's possible, which puzzle piece am I missing? Is this merely a question of adjusting the `.specs` file for GCC to point the linker to the right place? From what I see so far, that would still be missing the GCC runtime (`libgcc` and `libgcc_s`) which, during my build, have only been built for x86_64.

Comment: Given the differences in `libc` and the header files, isn't it a lot easier to just run FreeBSD in a virtual machine and do your compilation natively?

Comment: @RolandSmith: unfortunately (for me), no it's not. If you *ever* had to maintain build machines with compilers for more than a dozen separate targets, you'd do almost anything to cut down on that number. And it's not just that old FreeBSD, it's old Linux, AIX, Solaris and so on too. Would you honestly suggest to set up a Windows 2000 machine ancient VS to target W2K? Probably not. Also, if you ever tried to run really ancient kernels in a hypervisor, you may have noticed something - or sometimes nothing at all :) ... it's enough that the tests need to run natively on undersized boxes.

Comment: W.r.t. Windows I just don't build windows binaries anymore. Not worth the trouble. And I write a lot of new stuff in Python which runs OK on 'doze. But if you really want to target FreeBSD 7.x, look at the source about how the system compiler for 7.x (which was gcc 4.2, IIRC) was configured and built. I'm not sure that you need to build for 7.x for it to run though. The shared library versions for `libc` and `libm` haven't changed in a long time. Case in point, I've got TeXLive 2014 binaries (built for FreeBSD 7.2) happily running on FreeBSD 10.1.

Comment: @RolandSmith: lucky you. We need to build binaries. No Python, except in select places. However, I think there's a fallacy in your example. It would seem natural that software X built for FreeBSD 7 would run on FreeBSD 10. The same holds for software linking to glibc (in most cases, anyway), or when directly using syscalls. However, from this you should not assume that you can build software targeting FreeBSD 10 and run it without problem on FreeBSD 7. In fact that's the idea of this whole troublesome exercise. Pick a starting point and claim compatibility from, say, 7 onwards.

Comment: @RolandSmith: the configuration for GCC in the source is a very good hint, though. Although, of course, building a cross-compiler tends to be somewhat more convoluted than building a native compiler (host == target).

Comment: It's not natural. Sometimes the major version numbers of libc of libm needs to change because of incompatibilities. Ironically FreeBSD has a lot toolchain ports to cross-build for other environments, but the other way around seems pretty rare. Note that you can run some Linux binaries on FreeBSD. Haven't need to try that, though.

Comment: Any reference to "Debian multiarch" or just "multiarch" is unrelated to what you want. What you want is called "multilib".

Comment: @o11c: excellent. Thanks. I'll post an answer to my own question, if I come up with a solution first.